# Microsoft WebDriver hangs while starting new Edge session, does not respond to further requests

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

## Opening post

I'm using [the Microsoft WebDriver server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212) to automate Microsoft Edge.

I was able to start up the browser the first 2-3 times I tried, but subsequent attempts seem to result in the WebDriver server hanging. When I send the new-session command:

1. The WebDriver server logs that it received the /session request.
2. Any existing instance of Edge is forcibly killed by the server.
3. A new Edge window opens (to the New Tab page).
4. Nothing else happens. **The WebDriver server never sends a response.**

Edge is perfectly usable at this time. I can manually navigate it to pages and it appears otherwise fully functional.

On the other hand, the WebDriver server will not respond to other requests while the new-session request is pending. For example, `curl http://192.168.20.248:4444/status` will just hang, and the server also doesn't log any incoming requests. (I guess this could possibly be intended behavior, though?)

If I manually close Edge, **then** the WebDriver server sends a response: `{"sessionId":null,"status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error"}}`

Any ideas what could be going wrong? Are there any logs or other diagnostic information I can collect to help debug?

#### Details

I'm running Edge build 10240 (and Windows 10 build 10240, i.e., the public release). I've reproduced this both in a virtual machine and on a physical one.

On the Windows 10 machine, I'm running the WebDriver server in a Command Prompt with administrative privileges:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Driver\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" --port=4444 --host=192.168.20.248
```

On a separate Linux machine, I'm running this client code. It hangs before reaching the `.get` calls.

```py
import logging
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

try:
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://192.168.20.248:4444',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    driver.get('http://www.example.com')
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException as e:
    logging.warning('caught error: %s' % e)
```

I can also reproduce the behavior just using the raw wire protocol, for whatever that's worth. The curl to `/session` never finishes.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

wd_remote="http://192.168.20.248:4444"

echo "STATUS: $(curl -s ${wd_remote}/status)"

resp=$(curl -sd '{"desiredCapabilities": {"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge"}}' "${wd_remote}/session")
session_id=$(echo "${resp}" | sed -rn 's/.*"sessionId":"([^"]+).*/\1/ p')
if [[ -z "${session_id}" ]]; then
    echo "error starting session: ${resp}"
    exit 1
fi
echo "started session ${session_id}"
curl -s -d '{"url": "http://www.google.com"}' "${wd_remote}/session/${session_id}/url"
curl -s -XDELETE "${wd_remote}/session/${session_id}"
echo "quit session ${session_id}"
```

## Update (wilx)

I can see response from the EdgeWebDriver after several minutes which indicates timeout:

```
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 10:38:19 GMT[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Length: 60[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2016-01-20 11:38:19 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire:86 - http-outgoing-3 << "{"sessionId":null,"status":21,"value":{"message":"Timeout"}}"
```

Comment: +1 here. I have also tried version [WebDriver for Windows Insiders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48740) which seems few months newer. Still, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I currently need to work with an automated Edge browser, too. 
From what I know until now, starting a WebDriver on a different IP than "localhost" needs an elevated command line. Otherwise I get an Error: "HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup failed with 183".

But as far as I understood from [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1779165/microsoft-webdriver-hangs-while-starting-new-edge-session-does-not-respond-to-further-requests), running in an elevated cmd is not supported by now, what leads to the problem, that an Edge browser is currently only automatable from the machine running the browser itself.

Comment: I tried to start the driver from Java application that is itself started using unelevated prompt and it would not even start. With elevated prompt it at least starts the driver.